# C# WebApi request won't reach endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have built an api to handle my application and i'm using a controller to upload files with [FlowJS](https://github.com/flowjs/). It works with no problems on my local machine and also on my development server but when i use it on my client's homologation server i get a problem with the requisitions.

After some requests, it's a random number or requests sometimes 5 sometimes 10, the next request just freezes and won't respond and if i try to duplicate it using Chrome dev console it works.

This is a print of the requests:

[image: List of requests to the api]

The controller and service that are called only have IO operations and i'm logging everything that is done there after the request reaches the controller and when i get that pending status then request isn't logged.

I have also tried to work around my DNS to check if it was a connection problem due to the amount of requisitions but the problem remais the same. What else could be happening here ?

Comment: you're still getting a 200 status on the requests that are taking a long time?

Comment: No, it stays like this indefinitely but if i use the option to resend the request it will work but it "breaks" my app since the plugin won't get the response from the original request

Comment: And it's the same endpoint as all the previous request that worked?

Comment: Yes it is, it calls the endpoint to upload the file, every upload attempt sends two requests, the first check if the file chunk exists and the second one uploads the chunk if it doesn't exists

Comment: Odd, that suggests it's something on the receiving end.  But, really hard to tell from here :)